Regex in powershell command
The command below matches all shares (C$ , Admin$ , test55). I need to omit any shares that end with $. Please help.
net view \\computername /all 2>&1 | select-object -Skip 1 |  ?{$_ -match 'disk*'} | %{$_ -match '^(.+?)\s+Disk[^$]+$';$matches[1]}


please provide a sample output

Here is the sample output of the above command
PS C:\Users\biswa> net view \computername/all 2>&1 | select-object -Skip 5 |  ?{$_ -match 'disk*'} | %{$_ -match '^(.+?)\s+Disk*'|out-null;$matches[1]}
ADMIN$
C$
test55.
From the above output I need to omit any shares that ends with $

the sample output that would help is net view \\computername/all 2>&1 not from your current code

A regex is somewhat limited towards matching combined fixed size and delimited (by spaces) strings. As a general solution you might consider the (custom) cmdlet ConvertFrom-SourceTable: net view \\Localhost /all | Select-Object -Index (@(4) + 7..99) | ConvertFrom-SourceTable



Match the candidate lines with regex \bDisk\b

Then exclude those whose first whitespace-separated token ends in $, with regex \$$.


net view \\computername /all | 
  Where-Object { $_ -match '\bDisk\b' } |
  ForEach-Object { if (($shareName = (-split $_)[0]) -notmatch '\$$') { $shareName } }

Note:

Simply omitting /all obviates the need to exclude the shares whose name ends in $; that is, the ForEach-Object call's script block can then simply be
{ (-split $_)[0]) }

Either way, the assumption is that the share name doesn't contain spaces; for a robust OO alternative, see below.



A superior OO alternative, using Get-SmbShare with its -CimSession parameter to target a remote computer:
(Get-SmbShare -Special:$false -CimSession (New-CimSession computername)).Name


You could use WMI instead. This way you get a list of objects you can filter on.
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName computername -Class Win32_Share | Where-Object -FilterScript { !$_.Name.EndsWith('$') }

Let me know if it works for you.

Hi FranciscoNabas , there is some access issue for which I am unable to use WMI command on the remote computers. It would be helpful if u would suggest the necessary regex on the net view command

As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., Get-CimInstance) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., Get-WmiObject) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) 7, where all future effort will go, doesn't even have them anymore. Note that WMI still underlies the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see this answer.
